# AngularJS communication from controller to directive

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive

My question is about the communication from a controller to a directive created in the context of that controller. In particular, I'm interested in what's the recommended/best approach in this situation.
I can think of three different possibilities:

**Using a watch in the directive**

In this case the directive sets up a watch one a variable passed in the isolate scope, and reacts to its changes:

```js
directive('customDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            variable: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$watch('variable', function (newValue) {
                // Do something
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Using events**

With the second solution, the directive sets up event handlers using the $on function on the scope, and it then reacts to events sent using the $broadcast function:

```js
directive('customDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.$on('customEvent', function () {
                // Do something
            });
        }
    };
});
```

**Using a control object**

The last option I've been thinking of is for the directive to populate a *control* object with the function that it intends to expose. The controller can then call the functions on this object whenever it needs to:

```js
directive('customDirective', function () {
    return {
        restrict: 'E',
        scope: {
            controlObject: '='
        },
        link: function (scope, elem, attrs) {
            scope.controlObject.fn = function () {
                // Do something
            };
        }
    };
});

controller('customController', function () {
    this.controlObject = {};

    this.performAction = function () {
        this.controlObject.fn();
    };
});

<custom-directive control-object="ctrl.controlObject"/>
```

Which one is considered the best practice in this case? Am I missing some other options?
Thanks.

Comment: Considering you were able to list these 3 valid options, I'd say you have at least some understanding of Angular. There is no right answer here. I'd say options 1 and 2 are the most common in my opinion and I personally use both depending on the problem that needs to be solved.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My personal preference would be to use an event.

**Using watch**

The only downside to this (that I can see) is that it introduces a small performance hit and depending on the code base, little things add up eventually.

**Using a control object**

I think this introduces strong coupling between the directive and the controller. Plus imagine a new developer to the project comes in and sees `this.controlObject.fn()` and they're like ... where's fn defined? And then you start searching.

Plus, what happens if you have a different directive that needs to know something from the controller? A new control object, a new function defined .. I don't like it.

**Using an event**

With a generically named event like "component.x-updated" you keep coupling to a minimum and more than that, a new directive (or modal popup .. or whatever) just needs to react to the event.

Comment: Thanks for the reply. One case I'm thinking about is when a directive is used to *angularize* an old style component that renders itself given an element id, something like new Component('#elemId'). In this case the component usually exposes a quite rich API. How would you expose these functions? Would you create event handlers for the relevant functions?

Comment: Are you talking about a plain old javascript or jQuery plugin of sorts ? If so, I would encapsulate that into a directive - I wouldn't initialize it in the controller. The same way jquery ui sortable is wrapped in a directive here: https://github.com/angular-ui/ui-sortable/blob/master/src/sortable.js

Comment: The latter. And that's what I'd like to do, wrap it in a directive, but allow the directive to be controlled based on external events that happen in the context of the controller.

Comment: It's really up to you which way you chose to implement ... it depends on your specific needs for the plugin/app. I would just be careful to not tightly couple the directive to the controller (but even that depends ... if it's used in a single place then it's not that important)